# invalid initializer in a struct pointer function

Tags: c

I want to pass a struct as parameter in a function. But it's failed when i compile it.
Here is my struct definition. It's defined in svm.h and declaration in svm.cpp

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
struct svm_model
{
    struct svm_parameter param; /* parameter */
    int nr_class;       /* number of classes, = 2 in regression/one class 
    svm */
    int l;          /* total #SV */
    struct svm_node **SV;       /* SVs (SV[l]) */
    double **sv_coef;   /* coefficients for SVs in decision functions 
    (sv_coef[k-1][l]) */
    double *rho;        /* constants in decision functions (rho[k*(k-1)/2]) 
    */
    double *probA;      /* pariwise probability information */
    double *probB;
    int *sv_indices;        /* sv_indices[0,...,nSV-1] are values in 
    [1,...,num_traning_data] to indicate SVs in the training set */

                            /* for classification only */

    int *label;     /* label of each class (label[k]) */
    int *nSV;       /* number of SVs for each class (nSV[k]) */
                    /* nSV[0] + nSV[1] + ... + nSV[k-1] = l */
                    /* XXX */
    int free_sv;        /* 1 if svm_model is created by svm_load_model*/
                        /* 0 if svm_model is created by svm_train */
};
....
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And here is my function definition. It is declared in syll_fragmentation.h and defined in syll_fragmentation.c
Declaration:

```
 void real_time_predict(struct svm_model *model, SAMPLE *sum_normal);
```

Definition:

```
 void real_time_predict(struct svm_model *model, SAMPLE *sum_normal) {}
```

In main function, i call this function :

```
 struct svm_model *model;
 if ((model = svm_load_model(model_path)) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cant load model file \n");
        exit(1);
 }

 SAMPLE *sum_normal = (SAMPLE*)malloc(sizeof(SAMPLE) * 91);
 mfcc_load_normalized_sum(sum_normal, sum_path);
 real_time_predict(model, sum_normal);
```

The error i got is invalid initializer, which reference with real_time_predict function. I'm using gcc to compile. And here is error log:

```
syll_fragmentation.c:217:13: error: invalid initializer
```

line 217 is declaration of real_time_predict function.I don't know why, please help me, thank you guys!!!

Comment: Show us some actual code or we can't help you. There are no initializers here--indeed, there's no code of any kind here, just declarations.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker yah, i will modify the question

Comment: I've never seen a compiler that didn't tell you what line it got the error on.

Comment: ...but lots of compilers that tell you the wrong line :-)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, true enough, however, the line number given by the compiler is 'always' within +- 1 line number of the problem line.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the actual error message

Comment: can you guys check again. I modified the question!!!

Comment: You seem to have the terms "definition" and "declaration" backwards.

Comment: @user3629249 i posted the actual error message

Comment: @aschepler, yah, i will modify it right now

Comment: Does syll_fragmentation.c include svm.h? What's the *smallest* thing you can reduce all this to that still gives the same error message?

Comment: @aschepler i include svm.h in syll_fragmenation.h. Is it the problem?

Comment: Probably not, if syll_fragmentation.c includes syll_fragmentation.h which includes svm.h.

Comment: the posted code excerpt is only a handful of lines long, not over 217 lines, as indicated by the error message.  Suggest posting a [mcve] that is short and demonstrates the problem

Comment: @aschepler do you think svm_model is problem?

Comment: I'm all out of wild guesses.